# Constant reference to temporary object

Tags: c++, implementation, idioms

Let's say there is a function like

```
void SendToTheWorld(const Foo& f);
```

and I need to preprocess `Foo` object before sending

```
X PreprocessFoo(const Foo& f)
{
   if (something)
   {
      // create new object (very expensive).
      return Foo();
   }

   // return original object (cannot be copied)
   return f;
}
```

Usage

```
Foo foo;
SendToTheWorld(PreprocessFoo(foo));
```

So `X PreprocessFoo()` function should be able to return original object or copy/modify and than return new one. I cannot return `const Foo&` as it may refer a temporary object. Also I don't like to create `Foo` on the heap.

Perfectly, `X` should be some kind of union of `const Foo&` and `Foo` that may be treated as `const Foo&`. Any idea how to do that in more elegant way?

My current solution:

```
Foo PreprocessFoo(const Foo& f)
{
   // create new object (very expensive).
   return Foo();
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo foo;

if (something)
{
   SendToTheWorld(PreprocessFoo(foo));
}
else
{
   SendToTheWorld(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not 100% clear on what you mean but if you just want to omit an unnecessary copy of `Foo` in the return value, make your function small (right now, it is) and rely on the optimizing compiler to take care of your problem.

Once the function has been inlined, the compiler will elide unnecessary copies of `Foo`.

(Note for the interested: NRVO (named return value optimization) *cannot* be applied here since no unique name can be assigned to all instances of possible return values.)

Comment: I cannot copy original object. It is pretty expensive and there is no copy constructor. It is only copied in extremely specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create the object in heap then you should create it before calling the function and pass a reference down there. Think of the nature of the temporary: the function creates the new object in stack and then returns, dropping its stack frame. So the object should either be there or it should be copied over there.

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` (in the calling function) is not used again after the call, you may be able to do it with a `swap` function (specializing `std::swap` for class `Foo` if necessary):

```
const Foo& PreprocessFoo(Foo& f)
{
   if (something)
   {
      std::swap(f, Foo());
   }

   // return original or new object
   return f;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but `new Foo()` should be simply `Foo()`.

Comment: You're right.  Maybe I shouldn't try to post C++ code whilst working on a Java project

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to return a Foo object instead of a reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo PreprocessFoo(const Foo& f)
{
   if (something)
   {
      // create new object
      return Foo();
   }

   // return original object
   return f;
}
```

Comment: Yep. But the goal is not to copy original Foo object. It is pretty expensive operation (there is no copy ctr).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your current solution? Copy-constructor for `Foo` could be omitted due to RVO. Reference to temporary object will valid all time while function `SendToTheWorld` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If the lifetime of your Foo object is not to be determined by just one piece of code, why not use a `shared_ptr` instead?

```
void SendToTheWorld( shared_ptr<Foo>& pFoo );

shared_ptr<Foo> preProc( shared_ptr<Foo>& pFoo ) {
    if( something ) return new Foo(); // wrapped in a shared pointer
    return pFoo;
}

shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo = new Foo();
SendToTheWorld( preProc( pFoo ) );
```

Comment: or step away from the const argument of `preProcess`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to create Foo on the stack

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are conflicting: you want the object to be an automatic variable, yet you want to have your say on it's lifetime.  It is impossible to return an automatic variable by reference.  You could return it by value, but that's too expensive.  My idea: if the cost of copying is so high, probably the cost of allocating on the free store is small compared to it.

You could use an output argument, and *most of the time* not copy the original:

```
Foo& preProcess( Foo& f ) {
    if( something ) f=Foo(); // hopefully something is special!
    return f;
}

Foo localFoo;
SendToTheWorld( preProcess( localFoo ) );
```

Comment: This seems clever. However, it overwrites the original `Foo` object.

Comment: You looked at the code.  Look at the text and find the contradictions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy one.

I see three ways to solve this, all of which come down to making copying cheaper. All require control over `Foo`, one requires control over `PreprocessFoo`, too:

1. Use a compiler implementing rvalue references (part of C++1x) and equip `Foo` with the necessary stuff to have them kick in and make copying cheap.
2. Read [Alexandrescu's mojo article](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403855) and change `Foo` to implement that.
3. Use the Programmer's Universal Cure: add another layer of indirection. Wrap `Foo` within some smart pointer-like object that makes copying cheap. This, however, will require dynamic allocation.

If you can't change `Foo`, then I don't see a way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more idea: If the condition (`something`) is fix at compile-time, you can make it a template parameter to `PreprocessFoo()`. Then you can use TMP to branch to two different functions with different return types.

Here's a sketch of that:

```
template< bool Cond >
struct to_the_world_sender;

template<>
struct to_the_world_sender<true> {
  typedef Foo return_type;
  static return_type preprocess(const Foo& foo) {return Foo();}
};

template<>
struct to_the_world_sender<false> {
  typedef const Foo& return_type;
  static return_type preprocess((const Foo& foo) {return foo;}
};

template< typename Cond >
inline 
typename to_the_world_sender<Cond>::return_type PreprocessFoo(const Foo& foo)
{
  return to_the_world_sender<Cond>::preprocess((foo);
}
```